Why does my VGA adapter still work without power?
I bought a VGA to HDMI adapter here https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08GZ159FJ/ and for some reason it still works without the power cable being attached to the adapter.
My intention was to partner it with a USB cable that has a power switch so that I can turn on and off an external display that has no power button.
However, when I plug the adapter alone without power line into the VGA port of the laptop, it creates a "ghost" display that I can "use" even without seeing anything. I looked it up and apparently VGA was not designed to carry power yet here it is, powering the adapter.
What is going on here and is there a way to cut off power from the adapter so that the "ghost" display disappears?


You're obviously using active converter (there is no other way to convert VGA to HDMI), so this may be your first problem: it's not an adapter, per se. What it is is a device that emulates VGA receiver and then converts the signal to HDMI. Also, since DE-15 connector delivers 5v power on one of the pins, for EDID, you may have your answer here. I think it's easier to procure a VGA monitor and use it straight. Unless that's not viable, then maybe try USB-HDMI adapter: https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-Premium-Aluminum-Thunderbolt-Compatible/dp/B083KV1BR3


it creates a "ghost" display that I can "use" even without seeing anything. I looked it up and apparently VGA was not designed to carry power yet here it is, powering the adapter.

This does not necessarily involve powering anything inside the adapter. If I remember correctly, certain pins are used for presence detection simply by measuring resistance to determine that there's something on the other end.
I'm 90% sure that's the case, because the computer can detect the presence of a fully powered-off display, even if it's unable to talk to the EDID chip at all (I've seen how it leads to the OS booting at 1024x768 whenever I power them in the wrong order, and also I used to have non-EDID displays long ago); and likewise the display can detect the presence of a fully powered-off computer and suppress the "No signal" popup, even though there's no identification chip on the computer's side.
(I don't know which pins, it might be mentioned in this patent.)
Since an adapter is naturally not pass-through but a whole "receiver" that terminates all pins internally, this will always lead to the computer detecting the presence of the adapter.

Is there a way to tackle this via software?

Depends on the OS. When my old laptop's VGA port broke and started thinking that it always had something plugged in, on Linux I was able to permanently disable the port (with a boot-time option), whereas on Windows I could only use the standard "Display" control panel to select the internal LCD as its only display – but that worked well enough for daily use, it didn't attempt to use VGA despite thinking it was connected.

This is how the Display simulators work. It's basically a plug, which causes a computer to "detect" display. There are used sometimes for computers that cannot have  a real monitor plugged in, but need to work as a remote desktop, for example. Adapters are notoriously bad at handling properly cable/receiver detection.
